# Integrating the complex function $(\tan(z) + 1)/(z^2-z)$ along the contour $|z| = 1/2$

Tags: contour-integration

I would like some help integrating the complex function $$\frac{\tan(z) + 1}{z^2-z}$$ along the contour $|z| = 1/2$.

I factored the denominator and then thought of setting $(\tan(z) + 1)/z$ as $f(z)$ but then it is not analytic inside the contour (i.e. not analytic at z = 0) so I cannot use the Cauchy integral formula. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is given

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gamma$ be the contour $|z|=\frac12$.
$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma\frac{\tan z+ 1 }{z^2-z}\,\mathrm{d} z&=\int_\gamma\frac{\tan z}{z(z-1)}\,\mathrm{d}z+\int_\gamma\frac1{z(z-1)}\,\mathrm{d}z\\&=0+\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-1}-\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}
\end{align}$$

The first integral becomes $0$ because the integrand is analytic on and within $\gamma$, since $\frac{\tan z}z$ has a removable singularity at $0$.  I'm sure you can finish it from here.

Comment: I thought that since $(tanz)/z$ has a removable singularity at 0, then the integrand is not analytic within $γ$? To finish it off, we would use the cauchy-integral formula on $dz/(z-1)$ right?

Comment: @Elli The removable singularity doesn't affect the integral.  By definition, the integral depends only on the function value on the path of integration.  Removing the singularity doesn't affect those.   $1/(z-1)$ is analytic on and within $\gamma$.  You need to use the Cauchy integral formula on $\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}$